# What is the Fourier Sine Transform of $\frac{1}{x(a^2+x^2)}$? (Please check my solution)

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

My textbook says that the answer is $\frac{\pi}{2a^2}(1-e^{-as})$ while my answer is $\frac{1}{a^2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}(1-\frac{e^{-as}}{2}+\frac{e^{as}}{2})$. Here is my solution:

\begin{align}
\hat{f_s} & = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t(a^2+t^2)} \sin{st}dt \\
 & = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int_0^\infty \frac{t}{a^2}[\frac{1}{t^2} -\frac{1}{(a^2+t^2)}] \sin{st}dt \\
 & = \frac{1}{a^2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int_0^\infty [\frac{\sin{st}}{t} -\frac{t}{(a^2+t^2)} \sin{st}] dt \\
 & = \frac{1}{a^2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \int_0^\infty \frac{t}{(a^2+t^2)} \sin{st} dt \right) 
\end{align}

Let this integral be $y$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
y & = \int_0^\infty \frac{t}{(a^2+t^2)} \sin{st} dt  \\
 & = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t}[1 -\frac{a^2}{(a^2+t^2)}] \sin{st}dt \\
 & = \int_0^\infty [\frac{\sin{st}}{t} -\frac{a^2}{t(a^2+t^2)} \sin{st}] dt \\
 & = \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \int_0^\infty \frac{a^2}{t(a^2+t^2)} \sin{st} dt \right) 
\end{align}

Differentiating $y$ w.r.t. $s$ twice, we get

\begin{align}
y'' & = a^2\int_0^\infty \frac{t}{(a^2+t^2)} \sin{st} dt  \\
 & = a^2 y \\
\end{align}

This is a second order differential equation, whose solution is

$$y= C_1e^{-as}+C_2e^{as}$$

Put $s=0$ in $y$ and $y'$, we get $C_1 = \frac{\pi}{4} = - C_2$. Thus, we get $$y = \frac{\pi}{4}(e^{-as}-e^{as})$$ or
$$\hat{f_s}=\frac{1}{a^2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4}(e^{-as}-e^{as})\right)$$ which is nothing but $$\hat{f_s}=\frac{1}{a^2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}(1-\frac{e^{-as}}{2}+\frac{e^{as}}{2})$$

Comment: Maybe not very important, but $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin (sx)}{x}dx = \pm \frac{\pi}2$, where $\pm$ is the sign of $s$

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out :-)

Comment: I'd suggest trying a contour integral in the upper half plane with a semi-circular contour ( excluding origin) as a limiting case to infinite radius.

Comment: The textbook is correct. Are interested in a way to prove the textbook result or do you just want to understand where you are wrong?

Comment: @OlivierOloa I guess if I know where it's wrong, I'll end up with the textbook's answer? The second option, please. :-D

Comment: Why not just set $
I(s):=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t(a^2+t^2)} \sin{st}\:dt 
$, then differentiate to get $
I'(s)=\int_0^\infty \frac{ \cos{st}}{a^2+t^2}\:dt = \frac{\pi }{2 a}e^{-as}$? It gives $I(s)=\frac{\pi}{2a^2}(1-e^{-as})$.

Comment: @OlivierOloa That was my initial approach, but I couldn't integrate that integral(the cosine one).

Comment: I can give you an answer with this path.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Sir, what is wrong with my approach? Thanks!

Comment: In the middle of your post you wrote 'Differentiating $y$ w.r.t. $s$ twice, we get' $y''= a^2\int_0^\infty \frac{t}{(a^2+t^2)} \sin{st} dt= a^2 y$, but the latter integral is not $y$. Do you see it?

Comment: @OlivierOloa I'm sorry, I cannot see! It looks just the same!

Comment: @Vibhu I'm sorry, I misread what you wrote... But when you use $y'(s)=\int_0^\infty \frac{t^2}{(a^2+t^2)} \cos{st}dt$ the latter integral is **not** convergent. At least in the usual sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41349/discussion-between-vibhu-and-olivier-oloa).

Comment: But $y'(s)=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(a^2+t^2)} \cos{st}dt$ and not $t^2$

Comment: @OlivierOloa I pondered upon what you said, and I think I cannot double differentiate $y$. I am an autodidact, so maybe due to that I do not all the intricacies. Is it true what I said about the double derivatve?

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Can you tell which is the incorrect step in my method? I read another answer here and I guess $y'' = a^2\int_0^\infty \frac{t}{(a^2+t^2)} \sin{st} dt$ is a valid expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing the change of variable $u = sx$, it is implicitly assumed that $s \neq 0$ (otherwise, the integral evaluates to $0$). This means that the middle expression of $y$ and the subsequent chain of differentiations (hence, also, the obtained expression for $y''$) are only valid for $s \neq 0$. To obtain a formula for all $s$, we must differentiate:

$$y = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{t}{t^2 + a^2} \sin(st)dt$$

Now there is a problem if we want to differentiate under the integral sign, because the integrand is not integrable in the sense of Lebesgue

**Edit**

The added content is elaboration on Olivier Oloa's comment on the original post.

As suggested, we can differentiate:

$$I(s) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{t(t^2 + a^2)} \sin(st)dt$$

to get:

$$I'(s) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos(st)}{a^2 + t^2}dt$$

(because the integrand is Lebesgue integrable and its partial derivative wrt $s$ is uniformly bounded, wrt $t$, by an integrable function)

One way to obtain $I'(s)$ is by using the Fourier transform of $g(t) = e^{-a|t|}$. It is given by:

$$\mathcal{F} (g)(t) =  \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{a}{a^2 + t^2}$$

Using the inversion formula, we get:

$$\frac1{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{a}{a^2 + t^2} e^{-it s}dt = e^{-a|s|}$$

Hence:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-it s}}{a^2 + t^2} dt = \frac{\pi}a e^{-a|s|}$$

Assuming $s \ge 0$, we finally get:

$$I'(s) = \frac{\pi}{2a} e^{-as}$$

So

$$I(s) = \frac{\pi}{2a^2} (C - e^{-as})$$

As $I(0) = 0$, we get $C  = 1$.

Comment: Thank you, Mr Hussain, for your help! I don't yet know the intricacies of integral, like topics discussed by you related to Lebesgue and Reimann integrals. Thank you for your time and effort. :-D

Comment: @Vibhu I am glad I helped. You're welcome

Comment: Can you tell me where did I falter n my approach? Thank you :-)

Comment: When you got $I'$, why didn't/couldn't you differentiate it again to get $I''$ ?

Comment: @Vibhu because I can't. The partial derivative, with respect to $s$, of the integrand in the expression of $I'$ is not Lebesgue integrable (hence, not dominated by a Lebesgue integrable function). I said "I can't" because personally, the only sufficient condition, known to me, is that the integrand have a partial derivative dominated by a Lebesgue integrable function. I mentioned at the beginning of the post what was wrong with your approach, so please tell me what exactly is it that you are still having a problem with

Answer (score 2):

If you differentiate,
\begin{align}
   \left(-\frac{d^2}{ds^2}+a^2\right)\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t(t^2+a^2)}\sin(st)dt 
  &= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(st)}{t}dt \\
  &=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(st)}{(st)}d(st) \\
  &=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(u)}{u}du=\frac{\pi}{2}.
\end{align}
Therefore, $f(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t(t^2+a^2)}\sin(st)dt$ is a solution of
$$
               (-D^2+a^2)f=\frac{\pi}{2} \\
               D(-D^2+a^2)f=0.
$$
The general solution of this ODE is
$$
                 f(s)=Ae^{as}+Be^{-as}+C
$$
Plugging into the ODE gives $a^2C=\frac{\pi}{2}$.
And $f(0)=0$ gives
$$ A+B +C = 0 \\
     A+B = -\frac{\pi}{2a^2}
$$
Also, $t=au$ gives
$$
       f'(0) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^2+a^2}dt=\frac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{du}{1+u^2}=\frac{\pi}{2a} \\
          \implies A-B= \frac{\pi}{2a^2}.
$$
Adding and subtracting the equations in $A$,$B$ gives
$$
                      A = 0, \;\; B=-\frac{\pi}{2a^2}
$$
Therefore
$$
       f(s) = C+Be^{-as} = \frac{\pi}{2a^2}(1-e^{-as}).
$$
Typically, the sin transform is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}f(s)$, which would give
$$
         \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t(a^2+t^2)}\sin(st)dt = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{a^2}(1-e^{-as})
$$



**Interchanging Differentiation and Integration:** You can differentiate with respect to $s$ for $s > 0$ because the improper Riemann integral becomes an alternating series where the error term is bounded by the first neglected term in the series. So you get uniform convergence of the alternating series, its first derivative, and it's second derivative in $s$, provided $s$ remains bounded away from $0$ by any small amount. To be more precise,
\begin{align}
   \mathcal{S}\{f\}(s) & =\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t(t^2+a^2)}\sin(st)dt \\
   & =
    \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(u/s)((u/s)^2+a^2)}\sin(u)\frac{du}{s} \\
   & = s^2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(u)}{u(u^2+s^2a^2)}du \\
   & = s^2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\int_{(n-1)\pi}^{n\pi}\frac{|\sin(u)|}{u(u^2+s^2a^2)}du \\
   & = s^2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}f_n(s)
\end{align}
This is an alternating series where $f_n(s) \ge 0$ for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$, and
$$
        \frac{2}{(n\pi)(n^2\pi^2+s^2a^2)}\le f_n(s) 
     \le\frac{2}{((n-1)\pi)((n-1)^2\pi^2+s^2a^2)} \\
          \implies    0 < f_{n+1}(s) \le f_{n}(s),\;\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
This gives you an alternating series for the improper integral, and, for any fixed $\delta > 0$, the series converges uniformly for $s \ge \delta > 0$ because the alternating series satisfies
$$
                \left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}f_n(s)-\sum_{n=1}^{N}(-1)^{n-1}f_n(s)\right| \le f_{N+1}(s) \rightarrow 0 \mbox{ uniformly for $s \ge \delta > 0$ as $N\rightarrow\infty$}.
$$
The functions $f_n(s)$ are infinitely differentiable in $s$, and
$$
   f_n'(s) = -2sa^2\int_{(n-1)\pi}^{n\pi}\frac{|\sin(u)|}{u(u^2+s^2a^2)^2}du
$$
So the series of derivatives of $f_n'(s)$ is also an alternating series which converges uniformly for $0 < \delta \le s < \infty$. You can do the same thing for second derivatives as well. By classical theorems of differentiation for such series,
$$
       \frac{d}{ds} \sum_{n}(-1)^nf_n(s)=\sum_{n}(-1)^nf_n'(s), \\
       \frac{d^2}{ds^2}\sum_{n}(-1)^nf_n(s)=\sum_{n}(-1)^nf_n''(s).
$$
The end result is that you may interchange differentiation and the improper Riemann integrals:
$$
    \frac{d}{ds}\mathcal{S}\{f\}(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t(t^2+a^2)}\frac{d}{ds}\sin(st)ds \\
    \frac{d^2}{ds^2}\mathcal{S}\{f\}(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t(t^2+a^2)}\frac{d^2}{ds^2}\sin(st)dt.
$$

Comment: Please tell, how did you write the first equation? Thank you for your time and effort!

Comment: @Vibhu : What aspect about it is bothersome?

Comment: I did noot get how did you write the first equation?

Comment: @Vibhu : I've added details of the common type of alternating series arguments found in Fourier analysis. It's a bit tedious, but you get used to being able to step most of the steps once you've seen them.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed points. I, however, cannot understand why this works and mine doesn't? Earlier I'd thought that the second derivative doesn't exist, but now as you've stated, it does. Moreover, you've used the second derivative to solve the integral. Is it possible that both your answer and mine are correct? @TrialAndError

Comment: @Vibhu : You can check right away that yours does not work. $\hat{f}(0)=0$ must hold (why?), but that's not what you get for yours.

Comment: Yes. Mine is indeed incorrect. _But the question remains, where did I falter?_ If I don't know that then I'll make mistakes again in future!

Comment: @Vibhu : In your first rewriting of $y$, you introduced a term that is not defined at $s=0$. So you can't evaluate the final expression at $s=0$ and have something equivalent to the original expression. And, you can check that, if you evaluate your first expression for $y$ at $s=0$, you get something different from what you get if you evaluate the last expression for $y$ at $s=0$.

Comment: Yes! That's such an obvious mistake in the last statement of $y$. But unlike you said, I have introduced $1\over t$, which I believe should be fine for $s=0$ as $\int_a^bf(t)dt$ should be same for $a\lt t\lt b$ and $a\le t \le b$. So introducing $1\over t$ should not cause any problem? Am I wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @Vibhu : $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(st)}{t}dt = \pi/2$ fails to hold for $s=0$. This function is $\pi/2$ for $s > 0$, is $-\pi/2$ for $s < 0$ and and is $0$ at $s=0$. There's where your argument breaks down. You've got that kind of behavior going on for multiple integrals. If you had gone back to $\hat{f}(0)=0$ when solving your problem, I think you would have circumvented the problem, because everything is nice for $s > 0$.

Comment: I have a small question. If we denote by $I(s) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{t(t^2 + a^2)} \sin(st)dt$, then we can differentiate under the integral sign to get $I'(s) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos(st)}{t^2 + a^2} dt$. Now the function $g(t,s) = \frac{\cos(st)}{t^2 + a^2}$ has $\partial g/ \partial s = -\frac{t \sin(st)}{t^2 + a^2}$, which (as far as I can see) is not dominated by a Lebesgue integrable function. So, what kind of sufficient condition for differentiating under the integral sign did you use in order to justify the differentiation? Thank you

Comment: @AhmedHussein : I put that part back for you at the bottom of the problem. You can justify the interchange using improper Riemann integrals, by analyzing using alternating series. This can be done for $s > 0$. You can take a look. Alternating series with monotone terms is one of the few places where you can get explicit error bounds in order to analyze uniform convergence. But, such things occur when dealing with Fourier transforms of monotone functions, even though the functions are not Lebesgue integrable on the infinite interval.

Comment: Thank you very much for the elaboration. I believe there is a small typo: shouldn't $\left| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(s) - \sum_{n=1}^N f_n(s) \right|$ be $\left| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} f_n(s) - \sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^{n-1} f_n(s) \right|$?

Comment: @AhmedHussein : Thank you for the correction. I fixed that now.